# ExtJS 4: What is the Proper Way to Perform Inheritance

Tags: inheritance, extjs4

My code:

```
Ext.onReady(function() { // Every property is declared inside the class
Ext.define('MyCustomPanel1', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    alias: 'mycustompanel1',
    title: 'I am a custom Panel 1',
    html: 'This is the content of my custom panel 1',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});    


Ext.define('MyCustomPanel2', { // HTML is declared inside the class, title inside the config, constructor overridden
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    alias: 'mycustompanel2',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),        
    html: 'This is the content of my custom panel 2',        
    config: {
        title: 'I am a custom Panel 2'
    },
    constructor: function(config) {
        this.callParent(arguments);
        this.initConfig(config)
    }
});        


Ext.define('MyCustomPanel3', { // Title and HTML declared inside config, constructor overridden
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    alias: 'mycustompanel3',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),        
    config: {
        title: 'I am a custom Panel 3',
        html: 'This is the content of my custom panel 3'
    },
    constructor: function(config) {
        this.callParent(arguments);
        this.initConfig(config)
    }
});

Ext.define('MyCustomPanel4', { // title and html inside of initComponent, title override in instance declaration doesn't hold. HTML property is empty on render
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    alias: 'mycustompanel4',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),        
    initComponent: function(config) {
        Ext.apply(this, {
            title: 'I am a custom Panel 4',
            html: 'This is the content of my custom panel 4'                
        })
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});            
Ext.define('MyCustomPanel5', { // title declared inside config, html set inside of initComponent. Both initComponent and constructor are used.
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    alias: 'mycustompanel5',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),        
    config: {
        title: 'I am a custom Panel 5'
    },
    constructor: function(config) {
        this.callParent(arguments);
        this.initConfig(config);
    },
    initComponent: function(config) {
        Ext.apply(this, {
            html: 'This is the content of my custom panel 5'                
        })
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});                
Ext.create('MyCustomPanel1', {
    title: 'I am custom Panel 1 - Instance!',
    html: 'This is the content of my custom panel 1 - Instance!'
})
Ext.create('MyCustomPanel2', {
    title: 'I am custom Panel 2 - Instance!',
    html: 'This is the content of my custom panel 2 - Instance!'
})
Ext.create('MyCustomPanel3', {
    title: 'I am custom Panel 3 - Instance!',
    html: 'This is the content of my custom panel 3 - Instance!'
})
Ext.create('MyCustomPanel4', {
    title: 'I am custom Panel 4 - Instance!',
    html: 'This is the content of my custom panel 4 - Instance!'
})
Ext.create('MyCustomPanel5', {
    title: 'I am custom Panel 5 - Instance!',
    html: 'This is the content of my custom panel 5 - Instance!'
})
```

})

Results (via JSFiddle.net): http://jsfiddle.net/HtPtt/

Which of the above methods is the correct way to create an object by extending an existing object? What are the advantages and disadvantages of each? Where can I find further information on ExtJS 4 inheritance other than what is already here (http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/guide/class_system)?

Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I asked this question on the Sencha forum and here's the answer I got from Saki:

> Whether you use constructor or initComponent while extending depends
>   on what you want to do. initComponent will run from the parent
>   constructor anyway, but later, after some internal variable have
>   already been initialized, so in some cases you want that, sometimes
>   not.
>
> In no case I would use renderTo in Ext.define because it causes the
>   component to be rendered immediately after instantiation and that is
>   not always what you want. Also, initConfig should come before parent
>   call in constructors, otherwise it's useless as config has been
>   already inited in the parent call.
>
> You may also want to read "Writing a big..." in my signature. This
>   document was written for a previous version of Ext so code examples do
>   not apply anymore but principles are same.

Comment: But what about using the `Config` declaration within `Ext.Define`...is this a good idea or not?  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

As per the things found by me at ExtJS 4 so far, following is the way in which I extend existing components (below is a sample component created on textfield).

I use the constructor approach and so far have not found any issues with it:

```
Ext.define('Ext.pnc.Textfield', {

extend: 'Ext.form.field.Text',

alias: 'widget.pnctextfield',

config:{
    focusCls:'focusClassFieldPnC',
    fieldCls:'baseClassFieldPnC'
},

constructor:function(cfg){
    this.callParent(arguments);
    this.initConfig(cfg);
    this.on('beforerender',this.beforeRender);
},

beforeRender:function(){
    if(!this.allowBlank){
        this.labelStyle = 'color:#ff0000';
    }
}
});
```

Hope this proves to be of help.