# Why am I being forced to use Ext.getCmp('id') instead of this.objectName?

Tags: extjs, this

When I reference a combobox using `this.stateComboBox` it fails. However, using the same syntax, it works fine for a text field.

Giving the combobox an 'id', I can reference it using `Ext.getCmp('stateComboBox')`. But, I know that is BAD practice.

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong? See notes at end.

Thanks

```
Ext.define('App.view.prospects.Show', {

    alias:                        'widget.prospectsshow',
    extend:                       'Ext.form.Panel',
    iconCls:                      'icon-prospects',
    itemId:                       'prospectsshow',

    constructor:                   function(config) {

        var cfg = config || {};

        this.phoneNumberTextField = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Text', {
            anchor:                   '100%',
            allowBlank:                true,
            fieldLabel:               'Phone Number',
            labelAlign:               'top',
            margin:                   '5 5 5 0',
            tabIndex:                  1
        });

        this.stateComboBox = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.ComboBox', {
            anchor:                   '100%',
            displayField:             'name',
            editable:                  false,
            fieldLabel:               'State',
            forceSelection:            true,
            id:                       'stateComboBox', // I hate using this. See note below.
            labelAlign:               'top',
            margin:                   '5 5 5 5',
            mode:                     'local',
            store:                     this.stateStore,
            tabIndex:                  22,
            triggerAction:            'all',
            valueField:               'id',
            valueNotFoundText:        ''
        });

        // Lots of objects removed for clarity....

        Ext.applyIf(cfg, {
            border:                    false,
            items:                     Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
                bodyStyle:            'background-color: #F1F1F1;',
                items:                 this.prospectPanel  // Not shown above, but contains this.phoneNumberTextField and this.stateComboBox
            }),
            frame:                     false,
            layout:                   'fit'
        });

        this.superclass.constructor.call(this, cfg);
    },

    setData:                         function(record) {

        // This works fine.
        this.phoneNumberTextField.setValue(record.phone_number); 

        // This fails. No error in console. Just does nothing. WHY?
        //this.stateComboBox.setValue(record.state_id);  

        // This works. But, I hate using 'id'. It is BAD practice.
        Ext.getCmp('stateComboBox').setValue(record.state_id);   
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use itemId instead of id. Get the object by calling:

```
this.getComponent('internalid');
```

To solve the issue I suspect that you're only creating the reference to early. You need to be careful what you do so you don't end up adding the object to the prototype rather than the inherited object.

Add all your things in initComponent rather than constructor.

```
initComponent: function ()
{

    // you can add things to config here
    var config = {
        anchor: '100% 100%',
        ...
    };

    // create your local var things here (don't forget to add it somewhere)
    this.combo = Ext.create('...');

    // apply new config to base config
    Ext.apply(this, config);

    // ExtJS does all the stuff with the config
    this.callParent();

    // from here you should be able to getComponent
    // not always true though depending on rendering
}
```

Comment: When I do that, I get the error message; "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'setValue' of undefined."

If it should work - then perhaps that provides a clue about what I am doing wrong.

To clarify, I changed the 'id' parameter to 'itemId'. Then, I changed the 'setValue' line to:

this.getComponent('stateComboBox').setValue(record.state_id);

That returned the above error.

Comment: Also, the suggestion to use this.getComponent('internalid'); does not explain why the object reference works for the textfield with this.phoneNumberTextField.setValue(record.phone_number); but fails for the combobox.

Comment: Hey thanks. Will give that a try again later. But, I was using initComponent (that is my standard practice) and went to using a Constructor because of another post I read.

[This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6555136/extjs-4-what-is-the-proper-way-to-perform-inheritance) shows 5 ways, and I know of 2 more I think. The real problem is that ExtJS allows so many methods, it is impossible to clearly understand the pros/cons of each, or why just one method can't always work.

Comment: Totally see the problem. I guess it's nature of javascript that gives you so many problems. I can only say that the above has been working for me pretty well lately with the exception of setting values to controls loading using ajax.